# Ionic tabs disappear when I dismiss a modal

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs

When I call the modalController.dismiss() method like this :

```
  dismiss() {
this.modalController.dismiss(); }
```

When I press on the back button : [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6HDC.png)
, the modal closed itself correctly [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBpGR.png) ,but the tabs disappear when I am redirect to the previous page (before present the modal). instead of displaying the tabs [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TDsJ.png).
Any idea to fix this ?
Thank you for your response.
Cordially, Will.

Comment: You're gonna have to show some of your code. It's unclear what the problem is

Comment: I do this, Cordially Will.